# ThreadPoolExecutor exits before queue is empty

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

My goal is to concurrently crawl URLs from a queue. Based on the crawling result, the queue may be extended. Here is the MWE:

```
import queue
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def get(url): # let's assume that the HTTP magic happens here
    time.sleep(1)
    return f'data from {url}'

def crawl(url, url_queue: queue.Queue, result_queue: queue.Queue):
    data = get(url)
    result_queue.put(data)
    if 'more' in url:
        url_queue.put('url_extended')

url_queue = queue.Queue()
result_queue = queue.Queue()

for url in ('some_url', 'another_url', 'url_with_more', 'another_url_with_more', 'last_url'): 
    url_queue.put(url)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    while not url_queue.empty():
        url = url_queue.get()
        executor.submit(crawl, url, url_queue, result_queue)

while not result_queue.empty():
    data = result_queue.get()
    print(data)
```

In this MWE, two URLs require another crawl: `'url_with_more'` and `'another_url_with_more'`. They are added to the `url_queue` while crawling.

However, this solution ends before those two 'more' URLs are processed; after running, the `url_queue` remains to have two entries.

How can I make sure that the ThreadPoolExecutor does not exit too early? Have I misunderstood ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: The `with` block will definitely shut down the thread pool executor right after you've submitted the initial jobs, but I think you might be able to do this without queues at all, since you already have the job objects that `executor.submit` returns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition where the check for more work to submit happens before new tasks are added from the other thread, you need to not exit the threadpool until you wait on all submitted jobs, and then check if there is more work to submit.

```
task_queue = queue.Queue()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    # exit when no task pending or to be scheduled
    while not (url_queue.empty() and task_queue.empty()):
        # submit new tasks
        while not url_queue.empty():
            url = url_queue.get()
            task_queue.put(executor.submit(crawl, url, url_queue, result_queue))
        # wait for one task
        if not task_queue.empty():
            task_queue.get().result()
            # process result here if needed.
```

You might want to use [concurrent.futures.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) with `FIRST_COMPLETED` instead of waiting on the first task in the queue if tasks have varying times.

```
tasks_to_wait = set()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    # exit when no task pending or to be scheduled
    while not (url_queue.empty() and len(tasks_to_wait) == 0):
        # submit new tasks
        while not url_queue.empty():
            url = url_queue.get()
            tasks_to_wait.add(executor.submit(crawl, url, url_queue, result_queue))
        # wait for one task
        if len(tasks_to_wait) != 0:
            done, tasks_to_wait = concurrent.futures.wait(tasks_to_wait, None, concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I am not smart enough to understand what you mean with concurrent.futures.wait. You mean instead of `task_queue.get().wait()`?

Comment: @MichaelDorner yes, if you have a very long task and a few short ones, you will be stuck waiting on the long task and not submit other tasks until the long one completes, using the `concurrent.futures.wait` will continue when the short ones end.

Comment: Thanks! How does `concurrent.futures.wait` work for queues?

Comment: @MichaelDorner it doesn't. it works with sets, i added how its done, and i just corrected the `.wait` to `.result`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it. I personally like your first solution more, but thanks for the complete discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the futures instead of a queue:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

jobs = []


def get(url):
    print(f"start getting data from {url}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return f"data from {url}"


def crawl(url):
    data = get(url)
    if "more" in url:
        submit(url.replace("more", "less") + "_url_extended")
    return (url, data)


def submit(url):
    print("Submitting", url)
    jobs.append(executor.submit(crawl, url))


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    for url in (
        "some_url",
        "another_url",
        "url_with_more",
        "another_url_with_more",
        "last_url",
    ):
        submit(url)

    while True:
        done_count = len([1 for job in jobs if job.done()])
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if done_count == len(jobs):
            break

    for job in jobs:
        print(job.result())
```